# Distribution of function of uniformly random variables

Tags: probability, uniform-distribution

I am sorry if there is no simple answer to this or the answer is completely obvious but I am approaching my wits end here. Probability isn't my forte, nor am I even a mathematician.

I am essentially looking at a matrix of Random variables $X_{ij}$ where each $X_{ij}$ is uniformly distributed $X_{ij} \sim U([0,1])$ and would then want to look at the sums of column variables.

In particular, I am interested in the distribution of a specific column sum minus the maximum of all other column sums.
$$
\Bbb
P\left(\sum_{i=1}^nX_{ij}-\left(\max_{k\neq j}{\sum_{i=1}^nX_{ik}}\right)<x\right) 
$$

Any comments or help would be appreciated, although doubts that there is an easy answer to this are starting to creep up on me.

Comment: It seems pretty complicated, but you can probably simulate this without much issue

Comment: Sadly, as I am trying to use this in an actually rather simple (I think) proof , simulating won't help me a lot.

Answer (score 1):

The distribution of a sum of n independent variables uniform on [0,1] is the [Irwin-Hall distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Irwin%E2%80%93Hall_distribution), whose PDF I will call $p_n(x)$. The PDF of the maximum of N such sums is the PDF one sum is the maximum, multiplied by N possible choices of this sum, and the probability each other sum is no more than the maximum:

$$
P_N(x)=Np_n(x)\left(\int_0^xdx'p_n(x')\right)^{N-1}
$$

For the probability in question, integrate the product of $p_n(x_1)$ and $P_N(x_2)$ over all $x_1$ and $x_2$ satisfying $x_1-x_2<x$:

$$
\int_0^ndx_1p_n(x_1)\int_{x_1-x}^ndx_2P_N(x_2)
$$

This probability is independent of the column chosen for $x_1$.